# External hard drive not allowing permission

Tags: hard-drive, permissions

My older mac recently kicked the bucket, and I decided to switch to linux on a newer laptop, My hard drive was fine, and I now use it as an external hard drive. The one problem though, is that I cannot access any of my files. I've tried getting permission and it says that I am not root, therefore I can't make any changes. What do I do?

Comment: Try to acess it in a terminal, using sudo permissions. Also, are you logged in as a non-limited user? More information would be nice. ~/anzkji

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try and change the permission using the following command as an administrator account or your account, if it's the only account you set up.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /<folder name or path>
```

The -R will take care of all the sub-directories while the 755 permission will give the OWNER full access, USER read and execute and OTHERS read and execute.

**Read = 4, Write = 2, Execute = 1**

**Read (4) + Execute (1) = 5**

**Read (4) + Write (2) + Execute (1) = 7**

These are applied to groups and there are 3 groups in the order 
**OWNER** followed by **USER** followed by **OTHERS** and hence **755**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, access it via Terminal, to get sudo permissions type:

```
sudo then the command to access your directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Nautilus (via Synaptic or Software Center), then, open terminal, type gksu nautilus and enter your root password. A file browser window (Nautilus window) will open and then you can access as root your external HDD. You can make any modifications. Nautilus will shut down when you exit terminal.

Comment: Which Nautilus? When I search Software Center, there are 4 results.